# Cannot import settings module in python

Tags: python, python-module

I'm trying to use settings module but is shows "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'" and whien I try to install the module it shows "Requirement already satisfied: python-settings in c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (0.2.2)"

```
import settings
```

import settings module

Answer (score 1):

try

`pip install python-settings`

to import

`from  python_settings import settings`

Comment: Still doesn't work it still shows "Requirement already satisfied: python-settings in c:\users\harsh\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (0.2.2)"

Comment: from  python_settings import settings

Comment: This is the correct import statement, according to the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/python-settings/). `import settings` is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual Studio, you can create a Python environment (just right-click on it, choose "add environment" and set your python version) in "solution explorer" and then right-click on your new Python environment and choose "Manage python packages...", there you can search and install what you need. If your IDE is not VS you can try to search same things there.